# Receiving message 'System.InvalidOperationException', Timeout expired when reading a table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a website that reads multiple tables in a database. I can display data, update data, and generally I am able to use the database, except for one table. Because I can read other tables it can't be the connection string.

The full inner exception is...

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

The table is being referenced using a scalar valued function.

```
USE [DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[User_LogoRelativeUrl] 
(
    @userId int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(MAX)

    SELECT TOP 1 
        @result = RelativeUrl
    FROM Media
    WHERE UserId = @userId AND TypeId = 206

    RETURN ISNULL(@result, '')
END
GO
```

UPDATE: This is the calling code...

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute (Name="dbo.User_LogoRelativeUrl", IsComposable=true)]
public string User_LogoRelativeUrl([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> userId)
{
    return ((string)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), userId).ReturnValue));
}
```

This is the code that calls the code above...

```
public static string GetLogoRelativeUrl(int userId)
{
    OnlineDataContext context = new OnlineDataContext();          
    return context.User_LogoRelativeUrl(userId);
}
```

This is the method that calls the one above this one...

```
public static string GetLogoDoctor(int DoctorId)
{
    string relativeUrl = string.Empty;

    relativeUrl = UserController.GetLogoRelativeUrl(DoctorId);
    MediaStatus status = MediaStatus.Unknown;
    string ImageUrl = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(relativeUrl))
        status = UserController.GetLogoStatus(DoctorId);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(relativeUrl))
    {
        ImageUrl = "https://www.test.com/phh/images/logo.png";
    }
    else
    {
        ImageUrl = status == MediaStatus.Live ? Rei.TestOnline.Web.SiteUtility.CombineUrl(AppSettings.GetMediaSiteUrl(), relativeUrl) : "https://www.test.com/phh/images/logo.png";
    }
    return ImageUrl;
}
```

UPDATE: I commented out this line and everything worked except that I didn't of course get the logo...

```
relativeUrl = UserController.GetLogoRelativeUrl(DoctorId);
```

I have manually executed this function using `Management Studio`, using the same sign on as the connection string, and it worked with no issues.

What could be causing the timeout?

Comment: well the code you posted has nothing to do with C# code behind.. please show us how you are calling the function in your C# Code..

Comment: As a guess I suspect you are not properly disposing of the connection object in your c# code. If you can show us that code we will know for sure. And unless you can share that code the best anybody can do is guess.

Comment: I added the code that is calling the function. I will show any code that will help resolve the problem but I thought I added the code that you were asking for. I will also add the code that calls the function I already added. There are multiple method calls and I'll add them all.

Comment: @Gary, post the DDL (CREATE TABLE, including indexes).  If you have no unique index on UserID and TypeID, SELECT TOP 1 will return any random row that meets the criteria.